# Pytorch: How to access tensor(values) by tensor(keys) in python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I have a dictionary with tensor keys and tensor values. I want to access the values by the keys.

```
from torch import tensor
x = {tensor(0): [tensor(1)], tensor(1): [tensor(0)]}
for i in x.keys():
  print(i, x[i])
```

Returns:

```
tensor(0) [tensor(1)]
tensor(1) [tensor(0)]
```

But when i try to access the values without looping through the keys,

```
try:
    print(x[tensor(0)])

except:
    print(Exception)
    print(x[0])
```

Throws Exception:

```
 KeyError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-34-746d28dcd450> in <module>()
  6 try:
  ----> 7   print(x[tensor(0)])
  8 

  KeyError: tensor(0)

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
  <ipython-input-34-746d28dcd450> in <module>()
  9 except:
  10   print(Exception)
  ---> 11   print(x[0])
  12 continue

  KeyError: 0
```

Comment: Why do you want this, instead of `torch.nn.Embedding`? It provides integer lookup, just like your example.

Comment: Anyway, the problem comes from the fact that `hash(tensor(0)) != hash(tensor(0))`, so lookup fails.

Comment: I am doing simple math operations using dictionaries in pytorch. I am not working with neural networks.  But the error seems to be weird

Comment: `torch.nn.Embedding` is just a lookup table. Nothing more than that, nothing fancy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's at least three issues here.

1. If `x` is a dictionary of `tensor` keys, then of course `x[0]` will not work.  `0` is not a key of it.  Hence the inner `KeyError` that occured during the other exception.
2. Not actually relevant to your errors, but `print(Exception)` is almost surely not what you want.  It prints the *class object* (if that is the right term) of the class `Exception`.  You likely rather meant

   ```
   except Exception as e:
     print(e)
   ```

   or more specifically, `except KeyError` (otherwise it will just catch every kind of exception).
3. The real thing: you don't want to use a `tensor` as key in the first place.  It's a mutable type, compared by reference, not by value.  Every `tensor(something)` call will create a new object, hashing to a different value than the `tensor(something)` you specified as key.

   Use the actual integers instead.

Comment: @arya-mccarthy So, from both of your answers, good workaround is to avoid tensor keys and use actual integers as keys. Thanks one upvote,one accept.

Comment: Yeah, I don't really know PyTorch specifically, but that `Embedding` Arya mentioned also sounds like a better idea if you actually work with embeddings.

Answer (score 7):

In PyTorch, hashes of Tensors are a function of their `id`, not the actual value. Because Python dictionaries use the hashes for lookup, lookup fails. See [this Github discussion](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/2569).

```
In [4]: hash(tensor(0)) == hash(tensor(0))                                      
Out[4]: False

In [5]: hash(tensor(0))                                                         
Out[5]: 4364730928

In [6]: hash(tensor(0))                                                         
Out[6]: 4362187312

In [7]: hash(tensor(0))                                                         
Out[7]: 4364733808
```

In order to achieve what you want, you could either use plain Python integers as keys, or use an `Embedding` object as `x`.

Comment: I am not aware of nn.embedding use cases. I will definitely give a try.